# Populating a Listbox with an external excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I need some help fixing this code so it could retrieve the 2 cols from the external file to load them in the `lbox_buscar`, not only the Column A.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  Dim SourceWB As Workbook
    Dim ListItems As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        With Me.lbox_buscar
        .Clear
        Set SourceWB = 
        Workbooks.Open("C:/List.xlsx", _
                                  False, True)
        ListItems = SourceWB.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:B6").value
        SourceWB.Close False
        Set SourceWB = Nothing
        ListItems = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ListItems)
        For i = 1 To UBound(ListItems)
            .AddItem ListItems(i)
        Next i
        .ListIndex = -1

    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You're intentionally reading from one column with the range you've set (`Range("A1:A6")`). How do you expect to read from two when you've written code that specifically says *read one column*? You should learn to understand the code you've written (or copy/pasted) before using it.

Comment: I forgot to use the range A1:B6

Comment: Transpose does nothing usefull on that range, and `ListItems(i)` will fail on a 2D array: you need to loop rows and columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can go this way:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ListItems As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Workbooks.Open("C:\List.xlsx", False, True) ' open and reference wanted workbook . NOTE : in your code there was a slash (`/`) instead of a backslash (`\`). is it ok?
        ListItems = .Worksheets(1).Range("A1:B6").value 'store its sheet1 range A1:b6 values in an array
'        ListItems = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ListItems) ' don't transpose, otherwise you'll get a 6 columns array!
        .Close False 'close referenced workbook and discard changes
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    With Me.lbox_buscar
        .Clear
        .ColumnCount = 2 ' set referenced listbox columns number 
        .List = ListItems fill referenced listbox
    End With
End Sub
```

but you can shorten it down to:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Me.lbox_buscar
        .Clear
        .ColumnCount = 2
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        .List = Workbooks.Open("C:\List.xlsx", False, True).Worksheets(1).Range("A1:B6").value ' open wanted workbook and use its wanted sheets range A1:B6 to fill referenced listbox items
        ActiveWorkbook.Close ' close just opened workbook and discard changes
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help you get what you have asked.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim SourceWB As Workbook
Dim ListItems As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open("C:/List.xlsx", False, True)

ListItems = SourceWB.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:B6")
With Me.lbox_buscar
    .List = ListItems
    .ColumnCount = 2
End With

SourceWB.Close False
Set SourceWB = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```